# android:inputType="textPersonName" allows all sort of text input

Tags: android

I am using the above property in one of my AutoCompleteTextViews, however I am able to enter special characters and numbers too. Need suggestions to limit the input type to only alphabets and no numbers or special characters.

Comment: try `android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"`

Comment: This is working, but I can still open the numeric view, but on typing nothing happens! Hey and Ive started to like the cactus :P

Comment: There's no catus without barbs... ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText state = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtState);

                Pattern ps = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z ]+$");
                Matcher ms = ps.matcher(state.getText().toString());
                boolean bs = ms.matches();
                if (bs == false) {
                    if (ErrorMessage.contains("invalid"))
                        ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage + "state,";
                    else
                        ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage + "invalid state,";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me flawlessly.

`EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);`

`editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{alphabetFilter, new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10)});`

`private InputFilter alphabetFilter = new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            for (int k = start; k < end; k++) {
                if (!Character.isLetter(source.charAt(k))) {
                    return "";
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };`

Comment: I am looking for an answer in which I manipulate the keypad and not handle the input..